# Erro ao debugar com Docker no Visual Studio 2019 com Windows 10 Home: O usuário atual não está no grupo "Usuários do Docker"

Tags: asp.net, docker, visual-studio-2019

Olá, eu criei um projeto Asp.net Core MVC no VS2019. Automaticamente, a primeira opção de debug é "Docker", porém quando tento executar, é exibido o seguinte erro:

```
CTC1010 O usuário atual não está no grupo "Usuários do Docker". Adicione-se ao grupo "Usuários do Docker" e, em seguida, faça logoff e logon novamente no Windows.
```

Todas as pesquisas que fiz indicaram para fazer o que a mensagem indica: adicionar o usuário ao grupo "Usuários do Docker", porém meu Windows 10 é Home Single Language, e por isso possui limitação no gerenciamento de grupos de usuários.  (Meu docker é Toolbox, pois o W.Home não possui Hyper-v.)

A [documentação oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/visualstudio/containers/troubleshooting-docker-errors?view=vs-2019) fala para ir em "Gerenciamento do Computador", e expandir "Usuários e grupos locais", porém essa opção não existe na minha versão do Windows. O atalho "lusrmgr" para a mesma opção diz que não pode ser usado na minha versão do Windows, e pede para usar "Contas de Usuário" do painel de controle, que também não possui gerenciamento de grupos.

Utilizar a função "Add-LocalGroupMember" no Powershell com nome de grupo "docker-users" ou "Usuários do Docker", diz que o grupo não foi encontrado. Ao listar os grupos com "Get-LocalGroup", não existe nenhum grupo referente ao Docker.

Utilizando o Interactive Shell do Docker, eu consigo executar uma imagem normalmente, a exemplo de:

```
docker run hello-world
```

Por isso, acredito que o problema seja na configuração do Visual Studio.
(Já tentei também excluir as pastas vsdbg e onecoremsvsmon, e já dei permissão para "Todos" em Propriedades>Segurança à pasta vsdbg).

Se alguém tiver uma ideia em como resolver esse problema, eu agradeço. Gostaria de usar o Docker com o VS2019 para fins didáticos.

Comment: Uma alternativa é você atualizar seu windows para a versão insider. Com essa versão (release 2004, que será lançada em breve) você vai poder utilizar o Docker Desktop pelo WSL 2 mesmo sem ter o suporte ao Hyper-V. Pode ser uma boa alternativa caso você não consiga esperar até ser lançado essa atualização.

Comment: Você já validou? Tenho quase certeza de que o Visual Studio não suporta Docker Toolbox.

Comment: @LuizCarlosFaria sim, não suporta. Eu adicionei uma resposta dia 25/02, mostrando na documentação que esse é o problema, mas a resposta foi removida por administradores, e por essa e outras experiências com péssimos admins, eu desisti do stackoverflow em português, por isso abandonei aqui.